# How to parse special characters with PHP?

Tags: php, html, json, html-entities

I'm using PHP and cURL to access a remote API. It returns a JSON result. The API returns user-posted content, so I expected some odd characters here and there. However, very simple characters such as – or ’ are being echoed out via PHP as Chinese characters (I'm aware those aren't true dashes or apostrophes, but rather some equivalent). Nonetheless, other websites manage to display them fine, so I'm not sure why they're echoed out as Chinese characters in my case.

For example: the character ’ echoes out as 鈥檙.

I've tried various PHP methods at my disposal to get them to encode or display correctly, including:

```
htmlentities()
utf8_encode()
htmlspecialchars()
```

and none make a difference.

Additionally, I've checked and my page does have

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

at in the `<head>` element.

Am I missing an obvious solution? I feel like I must be.

Comment: Check your DB Charset.

Comment: what's the charset of the page you curled?

Comment: L. feir, I'll be honest, I'm not sure how to check. It isn't a web page with a <head> element, it's an API return with a content type of application/javascript.

Comment: As an aside, you say that the en-dash in your text isn't a real dash. But it is! You're right about the quotation mark not being an apostrophe though.

Answer (score 0):

鈥檙 is not a special charter its unicode.  special charters are still ascii and takes 8 bits.

whereas unicode take 16 bits.

Have you tried removing

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: @Soviet,   what is difference between Did and Have?

Answer (score 0):

The API's HTTP Content-Type should give you an idea of the character encoding.  You need to view the headers returned by your curl request to see what encoding you're receiving.   Running curl from the command line will show you:

```
curl -v http://...
```

For example, `curl -v google.com` shows:

`Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Then you need to be sure that you are respecting that character encoding in your database, and in your HTML meta tag.

Answer (score -1):

So, I was just an idiot. I failed to notice that there was a conflicting meta tag on MY page adding the WRONG charset. Thanks to all who took time to try and help.

Comment: So what was the solution.?  Have you removed <meta charset   to resolve your issue?

Comment: You can not add one more answer to say thanks to all of us. You have to either prove that your answer is different from ours. or click accept button for one of the previous answer

Comment: So please either elaborate your answer or delete the answer.